# how to write jql query which will fetch data when issue is created or resolved or open or closed?

Tags: java, php, jira, jql

I want to fetch details of issues when something event occurs.
means : when new issue gets created I want to fetch that details
        event like from open to resolved , from resolved to closed 
how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For status changes the 'CHANGED' operator will be useful.

Eg.  'List all items closed today'

```
 status CHANGED TO Closed AFTER startOfDay()
```

For items created today:

```
 created > startOfDay() order by created
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracloud/advanced-searching-735937166.html